# Override a click event with another click event inside that element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<a id="clickme" href="#">
    <span>Text for link goes here</span>
    <button id="deleteme">X</div>
</a>
```

And the following javascript:

```
$("body").on('click', "#clickme", function(e) {
  //stuff here
});


$("body").on('click', "#deleteme", function(e) {
  //stuff here
});
```

How do I make it so that when I click `#deleteme` the click event for `#clickme` does not run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$("body").on('click', "#deleteme", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```